# searching a keyword in a pdf using and extracting the corresponding area, using lucene

Tags: java, pdf, lucene, keyword-search

Here is this code that tries to search a keyword in a pdf:
`

```
          File pdfFile = new File(pdfString);
              IndexItem pdfIndexItem = index(pdfFile);
              Indexer indexer = new Indexer(INDEX_DIR);
              indexer.index(pdfIndexItem);

               indexer.close();

             Searcher searcher = new Searcher(INDEX_DIR);
             int result = searcher.findByContent("Fusion", DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE);
             if(result==1)
          System.out.println("The document contains the search keyword");
          else
          System.out.println("The document does not contain the search keyword");
          searcher.close()`
```

this would work fine but it only says that either the document contains the keyword or not. what I wish is that if after finding the keyword(most likely multiple times), it extracts the area that the keywords is within it. ***by area, i mean the sentence that contains the keyword***. does it require to store the text of pdf in a file and then doing a normal string tokenizing or this would be done without storing the textual version of pdf?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "extracts the area that the keywords is within it" ? Do you want an x and y coordinates in the pdf or simply its location in the text?

Comment: Is your PDF a tagged PDF? Also, can you post an example of what you mean by extract the area?

Comment: @ZiadHalabi by area i mean not just the keyword itself, but something like the sentence that contains the keyword.

Comment: @bot no, the pdf is a normal pdf. no password or any other thing made to make the pdf read only or unchangeable. however, i just want to know how can search a keyword in a odf and hen get at least the sentence that contains the pdf.